# UsB host on a motorola xoom

Tags: motorola-xoom, motorola

I have a MZ601 with android 4.1.2 and I try to run an app [DslrDashboard](http://www.appbrain.com/app/dslrdashboard/com.dslr.dashboard) for a Nikon camera. As it doesn't work, I ran the usb host diags and get the following message:

```
KERNEL
  claims support             yes
  device detected            yes
VERDICT
  os support                 yes
  3rd party apps             no
```

What does it mean? That USB host works, but I cannot run applications? The camera doesn't get recognized by the apps.

Is there any way to fix that?

Answer (score -1):

i noticed all the rooted MZ601 roms, have poor OTG support in the kernal, or next to none, i had the same issues with eternal USB DAC, not been recognized since the 4.0.4 stock ROM, after spending weeks , blowing images, roms, went back to the stock ROM 4.0.4, seems OTG support is not on their high list to things to do, only external USB hard discs.

the USB DAC is only 4 months old, so its not some special kernel patch, as the 4.0.4 is over 2-3 yrs old and worked, try going back tot the stock rom.